# iphone UDP listener/server - not getting data callback

Tags: iphone, sockets, callback, udp

I have a problem where I am not getting a data callback from a CF socket.  My application allows the user to set up up to 4 channels of data transfer (I'll call them "trials", since I don't know if channel means something specific.)  So far, I am only testing in the simulator, and am only working with UDP.  For each trial, I initialize a new instance of my socket driver class (called SimSocket for the simulator case, initialized as publisher or subscriber for send or receive respectively), send/receive a relatively small amount of data, then close the socket and release SimSocket.  Then I do another trial, etc, etc.

Here is how it fails: I set up trial #0 as a receiver, then set up trial #1 to send data to 127.0.0.1.  I start the receiver, then the sender, and data transfer works fine.  I can repeat this over and over, no problems.  Then, without changing any IP or port addresses or packet sizes or packet rates, I run just trial 1, so the data goes out to the ether or somewhere.  I don't see any issues in my console output when this happens.  Next I start the receiver again, trial 0, then run the sender, trial 1.  But now I never see any data callbacks, and trial 0 never gets any data to process.  My question is, why does trial 0 fail to receive data after that sequence?

Some supporting info....  I run Wireshark on the Mac looking at the loopback interface.  Even on the run where trial 0 fails, I still see the UDP datagrams in Wireshark that I would expect to see.  For the entire sequence described above, I see in my console output that sockets are always being opened and closed properly (except the last trial 0 that fails - it never gets to the point of closing of course).  All receive code is executing on the main thread.  When I send a set of data, I do that on a separate thread, but that is the same when things work and when they don't.  I can get this failure when sending 10 50-byte 'packets' of raw data at 2 Kbps.

Below are pertinent parts of my SimSocket implementation file.  I appreciate any help you can provide.  Thanks.

```
#import "SimSocket.h"

void simReceivedDataCallback(CFSocketRef s, CFSocketCallBackType type, CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info) {
    // NOTE: I don't know if I'm accessing the address argument properly here, or if it contains useful information!
    NSLog(@"SimSocket: simReceivedDataCallback function entry. Socket=%d, address=%s, port=%d", CFSocketGetNative(s), inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)address)->sin_addr), htons(((struct sockaddr_in *)address)->sin_port));
        // send data to SimSocket delegate here
}

@implementation SimSocket

@synthesize readyToUse, delegate, errors;

- (id)initWithType:(SimSocketConnection)connectionType1 host:(NSString *)host1 port:(int)port1 {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        hostStr = host1;
        port = port1;
        isPublish = YES;
        connectionType = connectionType1;
        readyToUse = NO;

        int sockType = (connectionType == SimSocketConnectionTcp) ? SOCK_STREAM : SOCK_DGRAM;
        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, sockType, 0);
        if (sockfd == -1) {
            NSLog(@"SimSocket:initWithType: Error with socket() - %s", strerror(errno));
            return self;
        }

        memset((void *)&address_in, 0, sizeof(address_in));
        address_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
        address_in.sin_port = htons(port);
        address_in.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr([hostStr UTF8String]);
        addressData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&address_in length:sizeof(address_in)];

        readyToUse = YES;
        return self;
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (id)initPublishWithType:(SimSocketConnection)connectionType1 host:(NSString *)host1 port:(int)port1 {
   if ([self initWithType:connectionType1 host:host1 port:port1]) {
      readyToUse = NO;
       NSLog(@"SimSocket:initPublishWithType: Successfully created BSD socket - %d", sockfd);

      cfsocket = CFSocketCreateWithNative(NULL, sockfd, kCFSocketConnectCallBack, simCallback, NULL);
      if (cfsocket == NULL) {
         NSLog(@"SimSocket:initPublishWithType: Error with CFSocketCreateWithNative()");
         return self;
      }
      readyToUse = YES;
   }
   return self;
}

- (id)initSubscribeWithType:(SimSocketConnection)connectionType1 host:(NSString *)host1 port:(int)port1 delegate:(id <SimSocketEvents>)delegate1 {
    NSLog(@"SimSocket:initSubscribeWithType: starting initialization with delegate %@", delegate1);

    if ([self initWithType:connectionType1 host:host1 port:port1]) {
        readyToUse = NO;
        NSLog(@"SimSocket:initSubscribeWithType: Successfully created BSD socket - %d", sockfd);

        delegate = delegate1;
        address_in.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        addressData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&address_in length:sizeof(address_in)];

        int yes = 1;
        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            NSLog(@"SimSocket:initSubscribeWithType: Error with setsockopt() with SO_REUSEADDR - %s", strerror(errno));
        }

        if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &address_in, sizeof(address_in)) == -1) {
            NSLog(@"SimSocket:initSubscribeWithType: Error with bind() - %s", strerror(errno));
            errors = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bind Failed - %s. Try using a Different Port number.", strerror(errno)];
            close (sockfd);
            return self;
        }

        CFSocketContext context = { 0, (void *)self, NULL, NULL, NULL };

        // TCP
        if (connectionType == SimSocketConnectionTcp) {
            if (listen(sockfd, 10) == -1) {
                NSLog(@"SimSocket:initSubscribeWithType: Error with listen() - %s", strerror(errno));
                return self;
            }
            cfsocket = CFSocketCreateWithNative(NULL, sockfd,  kCFSocketAcceptCallBack, simAcceptCallback, &context);
        }
        // UDP
        else if (connectionType == SimSocketConnectionUdp) {
            cfsocket = CFSocketCreateWithNative(NULL, sockfd,  kCFSocketDataCallBack, simReceivedDataCallback, &context);

        }

        if (cfsocket == NULL) {
            NSLog(@"SimSocket:initSubscribeWithType: Error with CFSocketCreateWithNative()");
            return self;
        }

        CFRunLoopSourceRef source = CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource(NULL, cfsocket, 0);
        CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), source, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
        CFRelease(source);
        NSLog(@"SimSocket:initSubscribeWithType: Current run loop = %x.  Main thread run loop = %x.", CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), CFRunLoopGetMain());

        readyToUse = YES;
        NSLog(@"SimSocket:initSubscribeWithType: Completed socket initialization successfully.");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    if (cfsocket) CFRelease(cfsocket);
    if (sockfd != -1) close(sockfd);
    [errors release];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)shutdown
{
    NSLog(@"SimSocket: shutdown: Am shutting down the socket.  sockfd = %d", sockfd);   
    if (cfsocket) CFRelease(cfsocket);
    if (sockfd != -1) close(sockfd);
}

- (void)sendBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(int)length {
   if (!readyToUse) {
      NSLog(@"SimSocket:sendBytes: socket not ready to use for sending");
      return;
   }

   int bytesSent;
   if (connectionType == SimSocketConnectionTcp) {
      bytesSent = send(sockfd, bytes, length, 0); 
   }
   else {
      bytesSent = sendto(sockfd, bytes, length, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&address_in, sizeof(address_in)); 
   }

    if (bytesSent < 0) {
        NSLog(@"SimSocket:sendBytes: Oops, error- %s. No bytes sent.", strerror(errno));
    }
    else if (bytesSent < length) {
        NSLog(@"SimSocket:sendBytes: Oops, error- %s. Only %i sent out of %i", strerror(errno), bytesSent, length);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"SimSocket:sendBytes: Successfully sent the packet (%d bytes) to %s", length, inet_ntoa(address_in.sin_addr));
    }
    NSLog(@"SimSocket:sendBytes: Current run loop = %x.  Main thread run loop = %x.", CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), CFRunLoopGetMain());
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

Folks, it looks like I found the problem.  When shutting things down, I was only releasing the CFSocket.  Following the lead of the UDPEcho sample project, I replaced this with 3 steps: a CFSocketInvalidate call, a CFRelease call, then set the CFSocket reference to NULL.  It seems to be working fine now.

Comment: This answer is acceptable to me.  However, I don't see how to accept it.  I don't see the "check box outline to left of the answer" that is mentioned in the FAQ.

Comment: BillC, it seems like you have two different accounts with the same name. You can see it by the two different reputation points, and by the two different user profiles (users 611823 and 496092). Try logging in with the 611823 account and you should be able to accept your answer ;)